# Present to indicate a habit?

Tags: present-tense

> If it is Kate Moss it will take all day but we spend  more time
>   laughing than working.

*David Bailey in an interview given to the guardian*

Why present for spend does it mean that is something he always does when Kate Moss is here (a kind of habit) but what is not usual is the coming of Kate Moss. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If it is Kate Moss it will take all day** but we spend more time laughing than working.

1) This is an interview, therefore spoken English.

2) **If plus present, is followed by will**. **If it is you, it will be interesting.** A simple conditional.

3) the simple present is  used in the second clause to indicate that in general those two people spend more time laughing than working.

Another example: If it is he, he will do the job but he spends a lot of time just messing about.

The first sentence is conditional and it is conjoined to another using **but**. The grammar is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Present tense **spend** there refers to the way things *usually* go when Kate Moss is involved: more laughter than work.  The present can express the usual, the typical, the regular.

P.S.The future **will** there expresses the idea that a session involving Kate Moss is likely to take the entire day because sessions with her usually do. It is prediction based on usual past experience. The future there is not at odds with the sense of the usual as expressed by present tense **spend**:  *... but we (always) spend more time laughing than working*.

Comment: what about the coming of Kate Moss does the use of the future indicates that it is not a regullar thing

Comment: Please see the P.S.